# Can't figure out why my pizza's bottom is very dry and firm

Tags: pizza, pizza-stone

I have a stone, I usually keep it in my oven ~ about 1 hour with 500F. The pizza turned out to be very tasty except the bottom - dry and firm (~6-7 minutes in the oven). What should I check?

UPD

The base is not just crisp, it's really hard to bite and chew.
My dough:

- flour 200g
- water 140ml
- salt 4g
- yeast 0.4g

The process:

1. I mixed water and flour, leaving for 0.5hour
2. Add yeast to a small amount of warm water
3. Add salt and yeast mix into the dough, mix to incorporate
4. Leave for ~40mins
5. Fold
6. Leave for 6 hours.
7. Bake

The recipe is from the "Flour, Water, Salt, Yeast" book.

Comment: I think you will need to add more information about how the base of the pizza was compared to how you wanted it. I think most pizza-makers want a dry base and it is common to aim for a crispy base too. 'Firm' is a bit too vague to understand your problem.

Comment: Also, sharing your dough formula and your process will help.

Comment: @dbmag9 The base is not just crispy, it's hard to bite and chew, I updated the post.

Comment: Which type of flour?  Are you baking directly on a stone, like a Neapolitan style?

Comment: @moscafj It's just a regular "all-purpose" flour. Yes, I put it right on the stone. Once upon a time, several months ago, when I just started using the stone, the base was not so hard (I used some different recipe) but I can't figure out why. The only significant different is that pizza was much thinner, and 5 minutes were pretty enough. Maybe it's because this pizza is pretty thick?

Comment: Are you mixing the salt and yeast together with water before adding it? Also, are you sure you have the recipe right? Do you really have more water than flour?

Comment: Gosh, 142% hydration pizza dough using general purpose flour with a probably rather low W-value for baking on the stone. How on earth do you manage to stretch such a thing?

Comment: I assumed he mixed up the water and the flour, but yeah..check that @mimic.  Something doesn't add up.

Comment: @GdD thanks for pointing. I confused here flour and water, please see the updated recipe.

Comment: @GdD I'm mixing the flour and water first. The separately - yeast and a little of water. Then add salt and yeast mix to the flour mix.

Comment: Salt kills yeast, it's advised you don't bring salt into direct contact with yeast in high concentration.

Comment: @GdD Thanks but I think my yeasts are totally fine taking into account how they grew up.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your water content is too high. I use a reciepe similar to yours to cause the exact effect you dont like. High water content cause a crust so chewy it is hard to bite through. Try 90-110ml of water instead of 200ml.

When the stone hits that high water content is does something similar to when you mist bread in the oven to make blisters.

Comment: Perhaps....70% hydration is high for Neapolitan pizza.  Try reducing to 60 - 65%, for starters.

Comment: Thanks, I will try out the next time (next weekend) and let you know if it worked or not.

Comment: I still want to know how he managed to stretch a 140% hydration dough.  that's not dough, it's pudding.

Comment: @FuzzyChef I mixed up the flour and water - here, not in reality.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect at least a part of the issue might be having too little alveoles (air bubbles/pouches) in the dough. If the dough size has not doubled after step 6 you might need a longer rise. If it has doubled you need to take care to work the dough in a way these bubbles not destroyed or flattened out before the bake.

In case you are aiming for a Neapolitan style with soft an fluffy dough a higher temperature and thus a shorter baking time would help to reduce the amount of evaporation that takes place.

In case you want a crunchier pizza adding some oil will help.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think it's the reason. The dough was more than perfect, it doubled after 3 hours or so and after 6 hours it was filled up with a LOT of bubbles. Even although I flattened it a lot when prepared, it raised great when baking, and the taste was delicious. But the base was firm like a stone...

Comment: I see, but I still have no clear imagination what your desired result is. Are you aiming for a Pizza Neapoletana, a thin Romana Tonda, a thicker al taglio or rather for an American style Pizza with a thick and fluffy base?

Comment: Sorry, @J. Mueller, I'm a noob in the pizza's classification... I can't answer your questions precisely. I wanted my pizza to be delicious (check), slightly crispy (check), and bottom to be slightly crispy, not the stone firm (ups).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to water content (per Adam Wheeler's answer) the other reason for unpleasant chewiness in a home-oven pizza is protein content and gluten development.  When you bake a pizza at 450-500F as opposed to 700-800F in a pizza oven, it cooks longer and can become tough.  The solution is to reduce the protein content [per Cook's Illustrated](https://www.cooksillustrated.com/recipes/1043-pizza-dough)(paywall).  By having a lower-protein flour and working it minimally, you get a more "tender" pizza when baking at a lower temperature.

I've used this recipe a bunch of times, and make a pizza dough that is 25% either semolina or corn flour to reduce the protein content, with less than 5 min of kneading, at 60% hydration.  Works quite well.  And if it ends up being *too* soft, you can tinker with the percentages, kneading, and rise time until you dial in the right consistency.

Comment: Thanks! What is in the recipe? How is it different from mine (I updated mine because I mixed up flour and water)?

Comment: Figured I could find someone on the interwebs who bootlegged it: https://www.craftybaking.com/recipe/cooks-illustrated-pizza-dough  That's the original, which uses cake flour.  I recommend using corn flour or semolina or even rye instead, to give it a bit more flavor.